# WCF PollingDuplexHttpBinding with Silverlight Client timeouts and errors

Tags: wpf, silverlight, wcf

Im building a WPF 3.5 desktop app that has a self-hosted WCF service.

The service has an PollingDuplexHttpBinding endpoint defined like so:

```
public static void StartService()
    {
        var selfHost = new ServiceHost(Singleton, new Uri("http://localhost:1155/"));

        selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(
            typeof(IMyService), 
            new PollingDuplexHttpBinding(PollingDuplexMode.MultipleMessagesPerPoll) {ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(1,0,0,0)},
            "MyService"
        );

        ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
        selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

        selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IPolicyRetriever), new WebHttpBinding(), "").Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());

        selfHost.Open();
    }
```

*Note: the IPolicyRetriever is a service that enables me to define a policy file*

This works and I can see my service in my client Silverlight application. I then create a reference to the proxy in the Silverlight code like so:

```
        EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:1155/MyService");

        PollingDuplexHttpBinding binding = new PollingDuplexHttpBinding(PollingDuplexMode.MultipleMessagesPerPoll);
        binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0);
        _proxy = new MyServiceClient(binding, address);
        _proxy.ReceiveReceived += MessageFromServer;
        _proxy.OrderAsync("Test", 4);
```

And this also works fine, the communication works!

But if I leave it alone (i.e. dont sent messages from the server) for longer than 1 minute, then try to send a message to the client from the WPF server application, I get timeout errors like so:

**The IOutputChannel timed out attempting to send after 00:01:00. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Send or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.**

Its all running on localhost and there really should not be a delay, let alone a 1 minute delay. I dont know why, but the channel seems to be closed or lost or something...

I have also tried removing the timeouts on the bindings and I get errors like this

**The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it has been Aborted**

How can I try to find out whats wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WPF uses wsDualHttpBinding, Silverlight - Polling Duplex.
WPF solution is simple; Silverlight requires ServiceHostFactory and a bit more code. Also, Silverlight Server never sends messages, rather Client polls the server and retrieves its messages.

After many problems with PollingDuplexHttpBinding I have decided to use CustomBinding without MultipleMessagesPerPoll.

web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="SlApp.Web.DuplexServiceBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="SlApp.Web.DuplexServiceBehavior" name="SlApp.Web.DuplexService">
            <endpoint address="WS" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" contract="SlApp.Web.DuplexService" />
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>      
</system.serviceModel>
```

DuplexService.svc:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="SlApp.Web.DuplexService" Factory="SlApp.Web.DuplexServiceHostFactory" %>
```

DuplexServiceHostFactory.cs:

```
    public class DuplexServiceHostFactory : ServiceHostFactoryBase
    {
        public override ServiceHostBase CreateServiceHost(string constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)
        {
            return new DuplexServiceHost(baseAddresses);
        }
    }

    class DuplexServiceHost : ServiceHost
    {
        public DuplexServiceHost(params Uri[] addresses)
        {
            base.InitializeDescription(typeof(DuplexService), new UriSchemeKeyedCollection(addresses));
        }

        protected override void InitializeRuntime()
        {
            PollingDuplexBindingElement pdbe = new PollingDuplexBindingElement()
            {
                ServerPollTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3),
                //Duration to wait before the channel is closed due to inactivity
                InactivityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(24)
            };

            this.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(DuplexService),
                new CustomBinding(
                    pdbe,
                    new BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement(),
                    new HttpTransportBindingElement()), string.Empty);

            base.InitializeRuntime();
        }
    }
```

Silverlight client code:

```
address = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:43000/DuplexService.svc");
binding = new CustomBinding(
            new PollingDuplexBindingElement(),
            new BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement(),
            new HttpTransportBindingElement()
        );
proxy = new DuplexServiceClient(binding, address);
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to you, thanks for the help, but Im not quite sure exactly what your telling me here, my code works fine, but my connection drops out and I cant stop it, will your code help this?

Comment: My code doesn't have problems with inactivity, and I think, it is because of CustomBinding without MultipleMessagesPerPoll. Anyway, try it yourself.